# Why is that JavaScript's strings are using UTF-16 but one character's actual size can be just one byte?

Tags: javascript, utf-16

according to [this article](https://2ality.com/2013/09/javascript-unicode.html):

> Internally, JavaScript source code is treated as a sequence of UTF-16 code units.

And this [IBM doc says](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=unicode-utfs) that:

> UTF-16 is based on 16-bit code units. Therefore, each character can be 16 bits (2 bytes) or 32 bits (4 bytes).

But I tested in Chrome's console that English letters are only taking 1 byte, not 2 or 4.

`new Blob(['a']).size === 1`

I wonder why that is the case? Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's right there in [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob): a Blob encodes string component characters as UTF-8, not UTF-16.

Answer (score 6):

> Internally, JavaScript source code is treated as a sequence of UTF-16 code units.

Note that this is referring to source code, not String values. String values are referenced to also be UTF-16 later in the article:

> When a String contains actual textual data, each element is considered to be a single UTF-16 code unit.

The discrepancy here is actually in the Blob constructor. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob#parameters):

> Note that strings here are encoded as UTF-8, unlike the usual JavaScript UTF-16 strings.

Comment: got it. are there any other ways to faithfully get the size (in bytes) of a given string in JavaScript?

Comment: I don't know of any built-in classes or functions that can do that, but I think you could iterate through the characters of a string to do it manually.

Comment: @Joji depends on what kind of encoding you're going to use. If you will to get length of string in utf-16 just use Buffer like this `console.log(Buffer.from('asdasd', 'utf16le').byteLength);` where `asdasd` is you string

Comment: Buffer is not available in browser right?

Answer (score 0):

UTF has a varying character size.

`a` has a size of 1 byte, but `ą` for example has 2

```js
console.log('a', new Blob(['a']).size)
console.log('ą', new Blob(['ą']).size)
```

Comment: "UTF-16 is based on 16-bit code units. Therefore, each character can be 16 bits (2 bytes) or 32 bits (4 bytes)."